# Add dynamic email address to post form

Tags: php, html, email, post

I have this code to post a contact form:

```
$pp = new FormHandler(); 

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['name','phone'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
$validator->field('email')->isEmail();
$validator->field('msg')->maxLength(6000);

$pp->sendEmailTo(''); // ← Your email here

echo $pp->process($_POST);
```

How can I add the `field('email')` which is the one entered in the email input field in contact form as the "send email to"..? Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Do you mean $pp->sendEmailTo($_POST['email']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean

```
$pp->sendEmailTo($_POST['email']);
```